# Hibernate: Specifying columns in a one-to-many relationship

Tags: java, database, hibernate, schema

I'm trying to build a Hibernate layer for a database schema I have essentially no control over.  Simplified, there are two tables.

Table **`parent`** has two important columns:

- `parent_id`, integer, primary key, autoincremented
- `parent_code`, string, unique key, generated by a black box somewhere (let's say this is a UUID for sanity's sake)
- Plus a bunch of columns of data

Table **`child`** has two important columns:

- `child_parent_id`, integer, primary key, autoincremented
- `child_parent_code`, string, foreign key pointing at the parent's `parent_code` value
- Plus a bunch of columns of data

I want to be able to call Parent.getChilds() and get a Collection of Child objects.  But setting up the Hibernate mapping files seems impossible.  What it's doing with the mappings below is searching the `child` table with the `parent_id` value (instead of `parent_code`).

In `Parent.hbm.xml`:

```
    <set name="childs" inverse="true" lazy="true" table="child" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="child_parent_code" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="foo.bar.Child" />
    </set>
```

In `Child.hbm.xml`:

```
    <many-to-one name="parent" class="foo.bar.Parent" fetch="select">
        <column name="child_parent_code" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
```

I've spent an hour poring through my copy of *Java Persistence with Hibernate*, but I can't figure out how to do what I want.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this in the parent:

```
<set name="childs" inverse="true" lazy="true" table="child" fetch="select">
    <key column="child_parent_code" property-ref="code" />
    <one-to-many class="foo.bar.Child" />
</set>
```

and this in the child:

```
<many-to-one name="parent" class="foo.bar.Parent"
    fetch="select" column="child_parent_code" property-ref="code" />
```

I have assumed that the code property in the parent is called "code".

Comment: @DavidM Is there a property-ref equivalent annotation in hibernate?

Answer (score 12):

I would consider using the hibernate annotations.  I found them to be MUCH easier to work with that the xml definitions.

Here's the code in annotation format:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="parent")
public class Parent
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="child", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Child child;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int id;

    @Column(name = "code")
    public String code;
}
```

Comment: This isn't relevant to the actual question is it?

Comment: It is related and personally I found it very helpful.